# File reading making PYQT gui unresponsive

Tags: python, image-processing, pyqt

I have a PyQt Gui application. After user interaction, a QThread is run,  in which three python threads are created for image file reading, cropping, and then writing the result. The python threads communicate using Queue.

With this setup I/O is around the disk's maximum, but it makes the GUI highly unresponsive. If on the other hand I put the  jobs into separate subprocesses, the GUI does not hang, however file reading speed is significantly reduced.

Is there any way I can speed up I/O using subprocesses?

Comment: Adding a time.sleep(0.1) after each file read make the gui responsive again. And it barely slows down the disk read speed

Comment: Can you post a minimalistic working example that shows the unresponsive GUI? You may have done something wrong with the `QThread` instantiation.

Comment: I solved it in the end by writing the image reading cropping and writing in C++ and calling it as a subprocess. No threads needed and the GUI is unaffected.